# An Ideal Related to a Polynomial Ring: Theorem 3.4 of Chapter XXI of Lang's "Algebra" (Revised Third Edition)

Tags: matrices, polynomials, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, free-modules

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct indeterminates. Let $R$ be an integral domain.  Let $\big(f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\big)\in R[x]^n$ be such that the ideal in $R[x]$ generated by $f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)$ is $R[x]$.  Also assume that $f_i(x)$ is monic for some $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

If $g_1(x,y),\dots,g_n(x,y),h_1(x,y),\dots,h_n(x,y)\in R[x,y]$ and there exists an invertible $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with entries in $R[x,y]$ such that

$\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix} g_1\\ \dots \\ g_n \end{bmatrix}
 =
 M
  \begin{bmatrix} h_1\\ \dots \\ h_n \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}$

then we write $(g_1,\dots,g_n)\sim(h_1,\dots,h_n)$.

Let $J$ be the set $\{c\in R\mid \big(f_1(x+cy),\dots,f_n(x+cy)\big)\sim \big(f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\big)\}$.  Prove that if $c,d\in J$, then $c+d\in J$.  Lang says this can be proven "easily."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assumption
\begin{align}
\big(f_1(x+cy),\dots,f_n(x+cy)\big)&\sim \big(f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\big)\\
\big(f_1(x+dy),\dots,f_n(x+dy)\big)&\sim \big(f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\big)
\end{align}
By substituting $x+cy$ at in $x$ in the second expression, we get
$$\big(f_1((x+cy)+dy),\dots,f_n((x+cy)+dy)\big)\sim \big(f_1(x+cy),\dots,f_n(x+cy)\big)$$
Consequently,
\begin{align}
\big(f_1(x+(c+d)y),\dots,f_n(x+(c+d)y)\big)
&=\big(f_1((x+cy)+dy),\dots,f_n((x+cy)+dy)\big)\\
&\sim \big(f_1(x+cy),\dots,f_n(x+cy)\big)\\
&\sim \big(f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\big)
\end{align}
thus proving the assertion.

Comment: Thank you for that!